# if 2 values in a dictionary belong to a same key, do they belong to the same key in another dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, compare

I am trying to compare to two dictionary to check the accuracy on a big dataset

I want to see if two points belong to the same key in dictionary 1, they belong to the same key in dictionary 2

I have way to much point to do a double for loop with "if points in both dictionaries"
i'm looking for a faster way to compare both dictionary

dict_1 has only 1 key for each point_id where dict_2 can have multiple key for 1 point_id

both dictionary look like:

`{key1 : [list of point id], key2 : [list of point id], etc}`

```
dict_1 = {key1 : [1,2,3,4,5,6], key2 : [7,8,9,10,11,12]}  
dict_2 = {key3 : [1,2,4,6,8,11,12], key4 :[2,5,7,9,10,11,12]}

def accuracy_from_dict_to_dict(dict_1,dict_2):
    total, truth = 0,0
    for key_dict_1 in dict_1:
        point_of_key = dict_1.get(key_dict_1)
        i=0
        while i < len(point_of_key): #for each point of the key_dict_1 list
          j = i+1
          while j < len(point of key):
              for key_dict_2 in dict_2:
                  point_i = point_of_key[i]
                  point_j = point_of_key[j]
                  if point_i in key_dict_2 and point_j in key_dict_2:
                      truth += 1
                  total += 1
                  j += 1  
          i+=1
```

The problem is not the code itself but more the computation time.
unless the data set is small enough, it's to long to be run

Comment: have you run this? it's not valid python code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are just checking 2-item combinations from the both dicts. You can do it better using [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools) module from the standart library:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

dict_1 = {'key1' : [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'key2' : [7,8,9,10,11,12]}  
dict_2 = {'key3' : [1,2,4,6,8,11,12], 'key4' :[2,5,7,9,10,11,12]}

c_dict1 = set(chain.from_iterable(combinations(v, 2) for v in dict_1.values()))
c_dict2 = set(chain.from_iterable(combinations(v, 2) for v in dict_2.values()))
total = len(c_dict1) + len(c_dict2)
similarity = len(c_dict1 & c_dict2) / total
print(total, similarity)
```

will print you:

`69 0.2753623188405797`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will try running it :)

Comment: What version of Python do you use? I have Python 3.5, everything works fine. This error can also be raised if you are trying to insert list as key. It will cause this error to raise in each Python version. Just don't use lists as keys.

Comment: found the problem that was on the point_id structure wich was [pt_id, [reference], group_id] which was not necessary. But I still have a time problem since it compare two big data set of thousands of points

Comment: I finally found a way to do it thks to you with the set parameter